# KDE: minimize a window without putting the window on the bottom of windows list

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde, window, kwin

Using KDE System Settings I have set a hotkey for minimizing the currently active window.

- The behavior I am used to is: I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, window minimizes, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I switch back to last minimized window
- Current behavior is: If I minimize a window with mouse click, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switching works as expected (switches to last minimized window). If I minimize with hotkey, the window is brought to the bottom of the windows list making it a pain to cycle through everything when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

To sum it up, how to minimize a window and then immediately unminimize it back, using keyboard?

P.S. In Openbox I was using

```
<keybind key="W-a">
  <action name="PreviousWindow">
    <interactive>no</interactive>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

maybe something like this is possible in KDE?
My KDE info:

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.6  
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.76.0  
Qt Version: 5.12.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Settings > Window Management > Task Switcher > Order minimized windows after unminimized windows: uncheck
[image]

Comment: This option doesn't exist. https://imgur.com/a/8B6Fwdc Please let me know your KDE version as well, I may upgrade

Comment: Yes, you are using an outdated Plasma version then. The option was introduced with 5.26.

Comment: Just saw that you're on 5.18. This is ancient by KDE standards, I really recommend that you upgrade.

Comment: Although I keep my Kubuntu 20.04.5 updated my version of KDE is 5.18.8, KDE Frameworks is 5.68.0 and QT version 5.12.8. So Kubuntu decides to use the older versions and leaves it to the user to manually upgrade the versions of the software.

Comment: If you're still on Kubuntu 20.04 then of course you'll only be getting the software that comes with Kubuntu 20.04, which is Plasma 5.18. If you want to use a newer Plasma version then you need to upgrade your Kubuntu to a newer version. The most recent Kubuntu version is 22.10, which ships Plasma 5.25, though Plasma 5.26 may be available through the backports PPA. Alternatively, if you want a distro with a stable Ubuntu base and up to date KDE software, you might want to consider [KDE Neon user edition](https://neon.kde.org/).

Comment: @lemontree Yes, I know that older versions come with older versions of software. I just commented it, because all mentioned software are different versions than OP mentioned. I don't want to upgrade to 22.04 LTS because of the snaps. I would have to change too many files to make my custom mousepointers, scrollscreens and more of that stuff cohesive. And my version is still supported and I like this site so I will keep it till it no longer gets security updates. Then I will choose, or update to 22.04, or change distribution. ( On another partition I run Mint and on another one Windows 10. )